# Convergence of two Sequences of random numbers.

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

In the prior question I proved if Z<sub>n</sub> ⇒ Z<sub>∞</sub> and Y<sub>n</sub> ⇒ C

 Z<sub>n</sub> + Y<sub>n</sub> ⇒ Z<sub>∞</sub> + C

Using almost sure convergence.

But the next question asks to show 'if Y<sub>n</sub> ⇒ Y<sub>∞</sub>, then it's not always true that Z<sub>n</sub> + Y<sub>n</sub> ⇒ Z<sub>∞</sub> +Y<sub>∞</sub>'

C is just a constant though, whereas Y<sub>∞</sub> is a random variable, not that it should matter, is the question asking me to give a specific example or prove with something I've missed? I've looked everywhere but can't seem to find even a hint.

Only seeking a push in the right direction, thanks!

Comment: Would you mind defining $\implies$? Is this almost sure convergence, convergence in probability, or something else?

Comment: The Yn ⇒ C is definitely almost sure convergence, but it only says 'in general' for Yn ⇒ Y∞